# Beginner Java- Why won't this compile?

Tags: java, string, methods, parameters, int

Why won't this program compile? It has 7 errors when I try to run it.

I am trying to do this:

> Write a method called inputBirthday that accepts a Scanner for the console as a parameter and prompts the user to enter a month, day, and year of birth, then prints the birthdate in a suitable format.

Here is an example dialogue with the user:

```
On what day of the month were you born? 8
What is the name of the month in which you were born? May
During what year were you born? 1981
You were born on May 8, 1981. You're mighty old!
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice2 {
    public static void inputBirthday(int number, String sentence, int number2){
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("On what day of the month were you born?");
        int number = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the name of the month in which you were born?");
        String sentence = console.nextString();
        System.out.println("During what year where you born?");
        int number2 = console.nextInt();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("You were born on" + sentence + number
            + "," + number2 + ". You're might old!");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `nextString()` method in Scanner. use `next() / nextLine()`

Comment: Can you tell us about these seven errors?

Comment: what are the errors you are getting ?

Comment: sentence,number,number2 variables are not declared in main method. they are local to inputBirthday() method.

Comment: Practice2.java:8: error: variable number is already defined in method inputBirthday(int,String,int)
   int number = console.nextInt();
       ^

Comment: @KumarKailash how do I fix this?

Comment: Hmm, a lot of thing missing here, where are sentence, number and number2 in your main method?

Comment: @flyingseacows - declare the variables as static (if you want them to be used in multiple methods).

Comment: This almost looks like a "find the errors and correct them" homework ^^

Comment: @X.L.Ant LOL. No, I actually spent a long time writing that very short code.

Comment: @flyingseacows happy you take it this way, I meant no offense.

Comment: @X.L.Ant No worries! I started learning java about 2 weeks ago, so even small programs like these take me forever!

Comment: What book are you using or university do you go to? I see this birthday question and example around so many times...

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine I'm currently taking APCS using the Building Java Programs book, 3rd edition.

Comment: Many more results from SO for that task: https://www.google.com/search?q=Write+a+method+called+inputBirthday+that+accepts+a+Scanner+for+the+console+as+a+parameter+and+prompts#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Write+a+method+called+inputBirthday+that+accepts+a+Scanner+for+the+console+as+a+parameter+and+prompts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code it will compile

```
     import java.util.*;

        public class Practice2 {

public static void inputBirthDay(int number,String sentence,int number2)
{
 System.out.print("You were born on" + sentence + number
                    + "," + number2 + ". You're might old!");
}

            public static void main(String[] args){
                 Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("On what day of the month were you born?");
                int number = console.nextInt();
                System.out.println("What is the name of the month in which you were born?");
                String sentence = console.next();
                System.out.println("During what year where you born?");
                int number2 = console.nextInt();
              inputBirthDay(number,sentence,number2);

            }
        }
```

The output is:

On what day of the month were you born?
21

What is the name of the month in which you were born?
septemper

During what year where you born?
1990

You were born onseptemper21,1990. You're might old!

Comment: However, using this, I will not being creating a new method called "inputBirthday", which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: now edited once check above  and run it in your compiler is it ok for you..!!!

Comment: Thank you! The main method runs fine, but how come the You were born on sentence won't print?

Comment: thanks! It works now. I have a question though. Why do I need to put inputBirthDay(number,sentence,number2); in the main method? How come it won't run without it?

Comment: the thing goes on is actually it is called as a stand alone application so every stand alone application starts executing from main method so that main method will get call default but where as inputBirthday is your own declared method so we ourself need to call it explicitly that is the reason i called that method from main

Answer (score 1):

You should call the function in main() method. Try this.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Practice2 {
int number=0, number2=0;
String sentence="";
public static void inputBirthday(){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("On what day of the month were you born?");
    number = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the name of the month in which you were born?");
    sentence = console.nextString();
    System.out.println("During what year where you born?");
    number2 = console.nextInt();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    inputBirthday();
    System.out.print("You were born on" + sentence + number
        + "," + number2 + ". You're might old!");
}
}
```

Comment: the variables in the main method (and the ones in inputBirthday) remain undeclared.

Comment: no i declared them globally

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's a so bad practice that I even didn't noticed you did. Sorry for not noticeing it, but please, don't do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your main method is the **entry point** to the application!
All the variables you call there are undefined because they're local variables declared in the method inputBirthday().

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to define variables before using in `main` method.

Second, once defined in `inputBirthday` method, variables must be used, not re-defined (they will be called duplicate).

Third, Scanned does not provide, `nextString()` method, use, `next()`.

And, these are very basic things, I would recommend you should first go through basic tutorials before doing hands on coding.

Comment: How would I define the variables before using them in the main method?

Comment: `String sentence = "value goes here"`;  like this, similar for `int`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `sentence, number, number2` are out of scope for Main method.So because of which you will be getting error.